# How to find the value between 2 characters within a field in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I have a table with a FirstName field that has some records containing nick names. For example

```
John "Johnny"
```

What I would like to do is pull out the "Johnny" into an aliased NickName field. I'm not quite sure how to do it.

```
Firstname   Nickname
John        Johnny
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select regexp_replace(name, ' ".+?"$', '') FirstName,
substring(name from '"(.+?)"') NickName
from names
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6728f/1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select 
    case when NAME(' ',name)>0 
         then SUBSTRING(name,1,CHARINDEX(' ',name)-1) 
         else name end firstname, 
    CASE WHEN NAME(' ',name)>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1,len(name))  
         ELSE NULL END as nickname
from Customers
```